# The constructor Peca() is undefined

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass, superclass

I am developing a work for a college assigment.
I have files, Validador.java, Peca.java, Tabuleiro.java

Validador.java:

```
public class Validador {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 0) { // sem argumentos


            Tabuleiro tab = new Tabuleiro("DD--"); 
            Peca peca = tab.peca(0,0); 



        }else if (args[0].equals("filtro")) { // argumento filtro

        }
    }
}
```

Peca.java :

```
public abstract class Peca {

    Tabuleiro tab;
    int linha;
    int coluna;

    public boolean isNada; //dps corrigir
    Peca(Tabuleiro tab, int linha, int coluna) {
        this.tab = tab;
        this.linha = linha;
        this.coluna = coluna;     
    }

    boolean vazia() {
        if(isNada == true) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Tabuleiro.java

```
public class Tabuleiro extends Peca {

    String repr;    
    char tabuleiro_array[][];
    int tamanho_tabuleiro;

    Tabuleiro(String repr) {
        super();
        this.repr = repr;

    }
    Peca peca (int linha, int coluna) {
        if(this.tabuleiro_array[linha][coluna] == 'D') {
           // return Rainha(tab,linha,coluna);
        }else {
            //return Nada(tab,linha,coluna);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And i am getting this error:
The constructor Peca() is undefined

```
    at Tabuleiro.<init>
    at Validador . main
```

I know that I could put Tabuleiro(String repr, Tabuleiro tab, int linha, int coluna) {
super(tab, linha, coluna)
However my professor told us that Tabuleiro could only receive a string... Tabuleiro(String repr)
Ideias?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a sample `String` that you would pass the the constructor of class `Tabuleiro` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have a Peca constructor in Tabuleiro. Instead, just pass the member data through super(data1,data2):

```
Tabuleiro(String repr) {
        super(); // pass information here super(data1,data2), this is used to initialize the parent class
        this.repr = repr;
    }
```

Comment: Well, tell that to my professor... I have to use it... is on the to do list

Comment: I try to remove that piece of code and I still have the same error

Comment: @PedroCosta You need to pass all the information that the constructor of the parent class requires through super(data1, data2) ->     Peca(Tabuleiro tab, int linha, int coluna) {

Comment: When I do super(tab, linha, coluna); inside Tabuleiro, I have this error:  Cannot refer to an instance field tab while explicitly invoking a constructor
        Cannot refer to an instance field linha while explicitly invoking a constructor
        Cannot refer to an instance field coluna while explicitly invoking a constructor

Comment: @PedroCosta tab should be an instance of the current class, are you passing the correct data? Please update your question above showing what you are trying to do and the errors that appear.